# boost::stable_vector insertion is orders of magnitude slower than std::vector. why?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm noticing a large performance difference between std::vector and boost::stable_vector. Below is example where I construct and insert 100,000 ints into both a vector and a stable vector.

test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/container/stable_vector.hpp>
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int size = 1e5;
    boost::timer::cpu_timer timer;

    timer.start();
    std::vector<int> vec(size);
    timer.stop();
    std::cout << timer.format();

    timer.start();
    boost::container::stable_vector<int> svec(size);
    timer.stop();
    std::cout << timer.format();
}
```

compile:

```
g++ -O3 test.cpp -o test -lboost_system-mt -lboost_timer-mt
```

output:

```
 0.000209s wall, 0.000000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.000000s CPU (n/a%)
 5.697013s wall, 5.690000s user + 0.000000s system = 5.690000s CPU (99.9%)
```

What is the reason for this huge discrepancy? My understanding is that both types should have similar insertion performance.

UPDATE:
boost version: 1.54

```
dev/stable_vector_test: g++ --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I added std::list to the code and tried passing -DNDEBUG in addition to -O3.

```
dev/stable_vector_test: make
g++ -g test.cpp -o test -lboost_system-mt -lboost_timer-mt
dev/stable_vector_test: ./test
size: 10000
vector:         0.000047s wall, 0.000000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.000000s CPU (n/a%)
list:           0.001168s wall, 0.000000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.000000s CPU (n/a%)
stable_vector:  0.963679s wall, 0.960000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.960000s CPU (99.6%)
dev/stable_vector_test: make opt
g++ -O3 -DNDEBUG test.cpp -o test -lboost_system-mt -lboost_timer-mt
dev/stable_vector_test: ./test
size: 10000
vector:         0.000038s wall, 0.000000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.000000s CPU (n/a%)
list:           0.000659s wall, 0.000000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.000000s CPU (n/a%)
stable_vector:  0.000752s wall, 0.000000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.000000s CPU (n/a%)
```

So with -O3 and -DNDEBUG I get comparable performance to std::list

Comment: You should probably look at the generated assembly to make sure the compiler did not optimize the first vector out since it isn't used for anything.  I doubt that will explain the whole difference since this should be a cheap operation, but it is always good to verify you are actually timing what you think you are.

Comment: Did you run it multiple times with consistent results? results for my system are: ` 0.000227s wall, 0.000000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.000000s CPU (n/a%)
 0.006458s wall, 0.000000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.000000s CPU (n/a%)`. It might be relevant to see at least gcc and boost versions involved at your site. You might also want to profile that stuff (or even break in gdb during that 5 second period).

Comment: As far as I understand, stable vector in worst scenario (implementation) will call new for each of the ints. Try adding std::list to your test and see if its perf is comparable to stable vector.

Comment: I tried using the vector to make sure it wasn't being optimized out and it didn't make a difference.I did run it multiple times with consistent results. I added an update to my original post with my boost and gcc versions. std::list results were also added above.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: interrupting gdb during stable_vector construction reveals that it's spending most of its time in resize

Comment: @kmanville: resize is probably allocating a new node, so it's probably spending all it's time in `new`.

Comment: Never underestimate the power of memory contiguity. More often than not, working in one block of memory will be faster (than anything), whatever the asymptotical complexities you are dealing with. In short, a simple `vector`, even with spurious copies, is mostly a golden hammer. vanilla `stable_vector` uses one call to `new` for each element. this is not reasonable. Maybe OK only if the stored types are large (>100 kiB ?). Memory fragmentation is a nasty perf killer.

Comment: the author himself made a benchmark and mentioned the problem, he cites "burst allocation" (like I mentioned in the comment on Nate's answer) can be a solution. http://bannalia.blogspot.jp/2008/09/profiling-stablevector.html and http://igaztanaga.vosi.biz/allocplus/#Chapter2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `stable_vector` doesn't use contiguous storage, it seems reasonable that it would take a lot longer than [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to allocate its initial memory.

As noted in [a background post on stable_vector](http://bannalia.blogspot.com/2008/08/stable-vectors.html), one possible implementation of `stable_vector` involves allocating a separate node for each element of the vector.  And sure enough, [the source code for the `stable_vector`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/boost/container/stable_vector.hpp) constructor shows that it calls `resize`, which calls `insert` with a pair of iterators, and `insert` performs N node allocations:

```
// (initialization...)
while(first != last){
  const node_ptr p = this->priv_get_from_pool();
  BOOST_ASSERT(!!p);
  //Put it in the index so rollback can return it 
  //in pool if construct_in_place throws
  *it_past_newly_constructed = p;
  //Constructs and fixes up pointers This can throw
  this->priv_build_node_from_it(p, it_past_newly_constructed, first);
  ++first;
  ++it_past_newly_constructed;
}
```

So it's doing something similar to [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list), which your data supports.

Comment: Yes, I was reading the doc of `stable_vector` before googling something in the lines of "stable_vector madness". Because 1. this changes nothing from `ptr_vector`, and 2. it falsely claims to be a vector, which it is not, like you said, it is an indexed `list`. I vote for the killing pure and simple of this non-sensical horror show. boost is not the place to post one's friends experiments at whacked containers. I don't understand how it got accepted, this must be a political joke.

Comment: Just to extend the discussion a little bit, I feel `stable_vector` could be made acceptable by the usage of a pooled allocator. This pooled allocator would be very simple to make since one only needs to store objects of 1 type. This allocator can simply track holes using a freelist. You can get around the overhead of individual node allocation thanks to that. Finally if `stable_vector` doesn't support custom allocators, overloading `new` for your contained type and make it redirect to the pooled allocator will solve the issue.